# Angular Protractor E2E-Test for PDF Content / Filestream Test

Tags: angular, pdf, web, protractor, e2e-testing

I need for our company an E2E-Test with Protractor. We use angular.

We need to test our Content in our PDF-Files. My Tests do something and after that I have the choice to download an PDF-File. But I don't know how I can test the content. If the content is right/wrong.

I hope anyone can help me :).
Sry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out a pdf-parser module like: [pdfreader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader)
This way you can:

1. Download the pdf file during test to a specific location
2. Open your file with your parser
3. Assert specific elements in the file

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Winify i will try it!